# Get someone wrong

Tags: phrase-request

How to say: I got someone wrong with someone else? Like I want to talk to Ben and I call you (while thinking you are Ben) 
And when I see you are not Ben, I say:
Sorry,  I got you wrong with Ben.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, the three most common ways to say that would be these:

> I'm sorry. I mistook you for Ben.
>
> I'm sorry. I thought that you were Ben.
>
> I'm sorry. I confused you with Ben.

In the second example, you can also drop the conjunction *that* altogether and just say:

> I'm sorry. I thought you were Ben.

Comment: You could use _mixed up_ as well: “I’m sorry, I got you **mixed up** with Ben.” Also, if the person you are talking to doesn’t know Ben, you’d probably use “someone else” in lieu of the person’s name: "“I’m sorry, I got you mixed up with someone else.”

Comment: Thank you. That's a good one too. I was thinking of *to get mixed up with someone*, but for some reason didn't include it.